# Error in c# compiling: Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#

I'm getting two errors, I see where they are, I just don't know how to change the code to fit my needs.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace zaidimas
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public int z1 = 1;
        public int z2 = 1;
        public int kauliukas;
        public string nuoroda;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button2.Visible = false;
            button1.Visible = true;
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
            webBrowser1.Navigate("siauliaicity.99k.org/zaidimas/");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Gaunama kauliuko reikšmė
                int kauliukas = RandomNumber(1, 6);
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = kauliukas + ".jpg";
                label2.Text = "Kauliukas ridenos ridinėjosi ir sustojo ties" + kauliukas + "taškais";


                int z1 = z1 + kauliukas; (first error goes here)
                string nuoroda = "http://siauliaicity.99k.org/zaidimas/index.php?z=1&z1=" + z1 + "&z2=" + z2 + "&plus=" + kauliukas;
                webBrowser1.Navigate(nuoroda);
                button1.Visible = false;
                button2.Visible = true;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Gaunama kauliuko reikšmė
            int kauliukas = RandomNumber(1, 6);
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = kauliukas + ".jpg";
            label2.Text = "Kauliukas ridenos ridinėjosi ir sustojo ties" + kauliukas + "taškais";

            int z2 = z2 + kauliukas; (second error goes here)
            string nuoroda = "siauliaicity.99k.org/zaidimas/index.php?z=2&z1=" + z1 + "&z2=" + z2 + "&plus=" + kauliukas;
            webBrowser1.Navigate(nuoroda);
            button1.Text = "Ridenti kauliuką! (Ridena: Pirmasis žaidėjas)";

            button2.Visible = false;
            button1.Visible = true;
        }

        // Kauliuko funkcija
        private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.Next(min, max);
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Error message's:

**Error 1   Use of unassigned local variable 'z1'   C:\Users\Tutis\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\zaidimas\zaidimas\Form1.cs 38  26  zaidimas**

and

**Error 2   Use of unassigned local variable 'z2'   C:\Users\Tutis\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\zaidimas\zaidimas\Form1.cs 52  22  zaidimas**

Any suggestions how to change the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already declared variable with names `z1` and `z2` you cannot declare them again

I think you wanted to use the same variable but you have accidently put `int` in start

change

```
int z1 = z1 + kauliukas; (first error goes here)
```

to

```
z1 = z1 + kauliukas; (first error goes here)
```

and

```
 int z2 = z2 + kauliukas; (second error goes here)
```

to

```
 z2 = z2 + kauliukas; (second error goes here)
```

Comment: Thanks Haris! Such a dumb mistake I made... Learnig.

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring the variable.

Change:

```
int z1 = z1 + kauliukas;
```

To:

```
z1 = z1 + kauliukas;
```

And change:

```
int z2 = z2 + kauliukas;
```

To:

```
z2 = z2 + kauliukas;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use like this

```
z1 = z1 + kauliukas;
```

and

```
 z2 = z2 + kauliukas;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are re-declaring your public variables as local variables in your click events, change the lines your getting errors on to:

```
this.z1 += kauliukas
this.z2 += kauliukas
```

This will assign the new value to your public variables.

Also, another suggestion for your random number code - don't re-create a `new Random()` you want to generate a random number, it is more reliable to use the same instance per thread, of if multi-threading using a `static` variable e.g.

```
private Random random = new Random();

...

private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    return this.random.Next(min, max);
}
```

See this article on the [Random Numbers](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

What is the sense behing `int z1 = z1 + kauliukas;` and/or `int z2 = z2 + kauliukas;` ?

Just do an assignment - i.e. like this:

```
int z1 = kauliukas;
```

AND

```
int z2 = kauliukas;
```

OR name your local variables differently:

```
int z1l = z1 + kauliukas;
```

AND

```
int z2l = z2 + kauliukas;
```

BTW: your code is a bit strange - why are you naming local variables identical to fields (`z1`, `z2`, `kauliukas`, `nuoroda`) ?

EDIT - after comment:

Just leave the `int` out:

```
z1 = z1 + kauliukas;
z2 = z2 + kauliukas;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var z1 = this.z1 + kauliukas;

var z2 = this.z2 + kauliukas;
```

You need to tell the compiler what's instance field and what's local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned any values in that scope..

you make a local variable in the button_click and try to set it to itself.. You can remove the int before z1.

Answer (score 0):

Well you've got how to make it work, but to me your real problem is

public int z1;

You shouldn't expose member variables like that.

```
public int z1 {get;set;}
```

would be better, but given what you are doing I'd have gone for old style.

```
private int _z1;
public int z1 {get {return _z1;} set {_z1 = value;}
```

Then

```
int z1 = _z1 + kauliukas;
```

would have helped you out not to mention the next poor duffer who has to read your code;

Juts because you can give a local variable the same name as a member doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 0):

you initializing variables in methods. You already declared fields `kauliukas, z1 ,z2` in your class and writing `int kauliukas = ...` you creating local variable with same name. So in your buutton1 and button2 click event handlers use `kauliukas = RandomNumber(1, 6);` and `z1 = z1 + kauliukas;` **without `int`**